# facebook comment plugin

Tags: плагин, facebook, комментарии

Возникла проблема с работой facebook comments plugin. Этот плагин подключен к сайту с помощью fb-приложение, на самом сайте поле для ввода комментариев отображаеться и если написать какой то комментарий, то модераторам (которые имеют доступ к управлению комментариями) они доступны для модерации, но на самом сайте при обновлении странички коментарии не отображаються (модератором комментарий одобряеться, результат тот же или даже выставить все коментарии доступны, результат тот же) В чем может быть причина. До недавнего времени все работало

Comment: Не пробовали спрашивать поддержку facebook?

Comment: Пока нет, сначала решил попробовать сам разобраться, но наверное придется  спрашивать у техподдержки. Смотрел на код, вроде как все  что написано в инструкции на facebook все так же. Я подумал может кто с подобным сталкивался, решил задать вопрос.